# Design becomes ugly after Pyinstaller builds app

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have an app on python+PyQt5, and I'm building it with Pyinstaller for MacOS by command:

```
pyinstaller --windowed main.py
```

It creates an "main.app" file in "district" directory, but then problem appears:

app becomes ugly! Firstly, when I'm running it without compilation it uses system current appearance. Compiled app is always light.
Secondly, it's something completely wrong with antializing or something related. Lines are ugly, some text is barely readable. Screenshots attached.

[image: Before compilation (light appearance)]

[image: After compilation (any appearance)]

Comment: As this is a Mac, I suspect it is a problem related to the retina mode. Looks exactly like 2x2 pixels are one pixel, which happens if the app doesn't explicitely support retina mode.

Comment: I tried to add
"QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)" (which, I believe, should enable retina mode support), but with no visible effect so far.

Comment: Sadly, that's all I got, I'm not too familiar with Mac programming :( sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the source of this angled lines was antialiasing. It was automatically switched on when launching from source (by system styles?), but it have to be switched on manually for compiled version:

```
qp = QtGui.QPainter()
qp.begin(self)
qp.setRenderHint(0x01) #have no idea why QtGui.QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing not working
qp.end()
```

Edit:
Actually, it really was a problem with retina.

```
info_plist={
    'NSPrincipleClass': 'NSApplication',
    'NSAppleScriptEnabled': False,
    'NSHighResolutionCapable': 'True'
     }
```

should be added to app call in .spec file